# Asp.net mvc ADD authentication account controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, azure-active-directory

I've created a project in Visual Studio 2017 with Azure authentication.
In my _LoginPartial.cshtml I see a line like:

```
 <li><a asp-area="AzureAD" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignOut">Sign out</a></li>
```

But I see neither AzureAD asp-area nor AccountController in the solution explorer.

Are they baked in microsoft dll's now?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right.

AzureAD asp-area and AccountController are baked in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI dll.

For the details, you could find [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI/).